# Is Texture Paint While In Viewport Render Possible With Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, texture-painting

Is it possible to texture paint while rendering with Cycles?

I've done it with EEVEE but can't seem to find anyway to have cycles viewport update while texture painting.

Comment: I had a similar circumstance where I was not able to see updates in the Cycles viewport.   I learned to live with it.  It was not essential for me.  I suppose you could have special circumstance that could be explained.

Comment: Language Language ....

Comment: So there's probably not a way to use cycles while in texture paint at this moment?

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess that this isn't possible at least without performance degradation.  The cycles integrator has to assume a somewhat static state of the shader, otherwise it is forced to restart the render every time you make a change.  So two things stick out in my mind.  Doing this would pause the viewport to such an extent it would become unwieldy, and it may be the case that cycles only updates the viewport when you change a noodle in the node editor, not when an image is changed.

Answer (score 1):

No, render view in Cycles will not update as you paint, no fix for this.

I have spent a lot of time painting in blender, and in the newer post 2.8 builds I find that either Solid View or Material Preview are the best to paint in regardless of which renderer I have set up, and for preview of the paint I swap to the Shading workspace to see it or just set up a duplicate editor in a small view and set that one to render view.